# JSON Decode Error When Running Python Choropleth Code

Tags: python, choropleth

Re-posting because my previous post was unclear.

I'm using the the link below to help create a heat map of positive tests in local zip codes. I have one data frame "Combined_POS2", which looks like this (it contains over 20 unique zip codes):

```
 Zip Code      Count
 21216         45
 21210         24
 21230         30
```

I would like to make a heat map where the colors are delinted by the zip code boundaries(like the state example in the link but for local zip codes).

Here is the Json file I am using https://raw.githubusercontent.com/millbj92/US-Zip-Codes-JSON/master/USCities.json

I am running the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import folium
from folium import plugins
%matplotlib inline
import geojson
import geopandas as gpd

Combined_POS2 = Combined_POS1['ZIP'].value_counts().rename_axis('ZIP').reset_index(name='counts')

url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/millbj92/US-Zip-Codes-JSON/master'
state_geo = f'{url}/USCities.json'

m = folium.Map(location=[48, -102], zoom_start=3)

folium.Choropleth(
geo_data=state_geo,
name='choropleth',
data=Combined_POS2,
columns=['ZIP', 'counts'],
key_on='feature.zip_code',
fill_color='YlGn',
fill_opacity=0.7,
line_opacity=0.2,
legend_name='Unemployment Rate (%)').add_to(m)

folium.LayerControl().add_to(m)
```

When I run this code I get this error:

```
  ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
    TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-290-fecdd8605e8f> in <module>
 10     fill_opacity=0.7,
 11     line_opacity=0.2,
 ---> 12     legend_name='Unemployment Rate (%)'
 13 ).add_to(m)
 14 

 ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\folium\features.py in 
 __init__(self, geo_data, data, columns, key_on, bins, fill_color, 
 nan_fill_color, fill_opacity, nan_fill_opacity, line_color, line_weight, 
 line_opacity, name, legend_name, overlay, control, show, topojson, 
 smooth_factor, highlight, **kwargs)
 1249                 style_function=style_function,
 1250                 smooth_factor=smooth_factor,
 ->  1251                 highlight_function=highlight_function if highlight 
 else None)
 1252 
 1253         self.add_child(self.geojson)

 ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\folium\features.py in 
 __init__(self, data, style_function, highlight_function, name, overlay, 
 control, show, smooth_factor, tooltip, embed, popup)
454 
455         if self.style or self.highlight:
 --> 456             self.convert_to_feature_collection()
457             if self.style:
458                 self._validate_function(style_function, 'style_function')

 ~\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\folium\features.py in 
convert_to_feature_collection(self)
501     def convert_to_feature_collection(self):
502         """Convert data into a FeatureCollection if it is not already."""
 --> 503         if self.data['type'] == 'FeatureCollection':
504             return
505         if not self.embed:

TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

I found this resource online but I'm honestly so new to Python and Json (my head is spinning with all of the material available), I'm not sure where to start in trying to figure out my issues. https://github.com/python-visualization/folium/issues/918

https://python-visualization.github.io/folium/quickstart.html#Getting-Started

Comment: You write "Here is the Json file I am using ..." but your code uses a different URL.  What happens if you change your code to use this URL?

Comment: The link is the raw file - I found the data here https://github.com/millbj92/US-Zip-Codes-JSON/blob/master/USCities.json

Comment: Yes, but your code isn't trying to load the raw JSON file (which it seems you want to do), it's trying to load the URL in your comment (which returns an HTML page) and attempting to parse this HTML as if it were JSON.  Put that `raw.githubusercontent.com` URL in the value of your `url` variable and see if that makes a change.

Comment: Ah - I follow now - the code is the same as above now expect I changed: "url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/millbj92/US-Zip-Codes-JSON/master'"
"state_geo = f'{url}/USCities.json'" . I am not getting an error that says "TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str".

Comment: Please edit your question to (a) update your code and (b) include the full traceback of this new error message.

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to plot a choropleth map using unsuitable geographic data.

To plot a choropleth map you need [GeoJson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GeoJSON) data, but the list of zip-codes you provided isn't GeoJson.  It appears to contain a single latitude-longitude point for each zip code. Nowhere in this file are the zip-code boundaries you mention.

Besides, it seems you want to draw a heatmap, not a choropleth.  In that case, try reading [this how-to guide](https://www.kaggle.com/daveianhickey/how-to-folium-for-maps-heatmaps-time-data#Heatmaps,-boo-ya!).

It would be nice if Folium could point out the error and say "sorry, this data isn't what we need" instead of failing with an obscure error at some point later.

Comment: I see now - I have code to create a blended heat map like the last two maps in this link https://towardsdatascience.com/making-3-easy-maps-with-python-fb7dfb1036. However, I want to create map like the one detailed in code cell 14 in this link, which uses json data and the Choropleth method. Sorry if I',confusing things.

Comment: @Raven: in that case you will have to find GeoJson data for zip-code boundaries.  Try to find suitable data just around the zip codes you have: there are 40,000 zip codes in the file you link to, and that is far too many to show on a choropleth.